# My selectToUISlider slides out of range and only updates value on click, not when you slide

Tags: jquery, rangeslider, jquery-ui-touch-punch

As seen here on top of the page: http://bit.ly/1HPqZ5j

It also doesn't work on mobile (cannot slide) although I added jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js

Comment: Can you provide some context?

Comment: What doe you mean by that? Sorry i'm new here.. I added a link so you can easily see how it - doesn't -work. Maybe this is a common problem?

Comment: Nobody will click your link. You should add your code to the body of your question.